# boost::get with boost::filtered_graph on adjacency_list with netsed properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, adjacency-list

I wrote a small wrapper for `boost::adjacency_list`:

```
    template <typename T>
    using VertexWithIndexProperty =            
          boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, T>;

    template <typename VertexProperty, typename EdgeProperty = 
                                    boost::no_property>
    class MutableGraph  : public boost::adjacency_list< boost::setS, 
                             boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, 
                             VertexWithIndexProperty<VertexProperty>, EdgeProperty> {
    public:
         using BoostBase =
          boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS,
                                VertexWithIndexProperty<VertexProperty>,
                                EdgeProperty>;
      MutableGraph() {}
      MutableGraph(std::size_t n) : BoostBase(n) {}
      MutableGraph(const MutableGraph &rhs) : BoostBase(rhs) {}
      MutableGraph &operator=(const MutableGraph &rhs) {
        static_cast<BoostBase *>(this)->operator=(rhs);
        return *this;
      }
    };
```

Then I use it as follows: I collect some vertex_descriptors in sets in order to create `boost::filtered_graph`:
`

```
using Graph = MutableGraph<boost::property<vertex_color_t, int>>;
Graph g;

std::set<int> C, H; //vertex_descriptors I collect

...

auto vertex_index_map = get(vertex_index, g);

std::function<bool(vertex_descriptor)> vertexes_filter =
      [&vertex_index_map, &C, &H](vertex_descriptor v) {

        auto index = vertex_index_map[v];
        return C.find(index) != C.end() || H.find(index) != H.end();
      };

   boost::filtered_graph<Graph, boost::keep_all, decltype(crown_vertexes_filter)>
           auxilary(g, boost::keep_all(), crown_vertexes_filter);
```

Everything is ok, but when I try to get any property_map for vertexes, for example: `

```
auto auxilary_vertex_index_map
          = get(boost::vertex_index, auxilary);
```

I get the following error:

```
could not convert

    boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, 
boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, 
boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, 
boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, int> >, 
boost::no_property, boost::no_property, boost::listS>, int, 
int&, boost::vertex_index_t>

to 

 boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map<MutableGraph<
 boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, int> >,
 int, 
 int&,
 boost::vertex_index_t>
```

I get this error in

```
template <typename G, typename EP, typename VP, typename Property>
  typename property_map<G, Property>::type
  get(Property p, filtered_graph<G, EP, VP>& g)
  {
    return get(p, const_cast<G&>(g.m_g));
  }
```

in `filtered_graph.hpp`.

I don't understand why this is happening, whether because of my wrapper or because of what I decided to use nested properties instead of bundled ones.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest that `MutableGraph` is not the best name for your type because it duplicates the concept name from the Boost Graph Library. That's at best confusing in error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested properties are known as "interior properties". They're not your problem.

Instead your problem is with the VertexContainerSelector argument (`boost::listS`). It causes the `vertex_descriptor` type to be

- not integral (instead it's an opaque type now)
- not double as the de-factor vertex index

You already know this, which is why you added a property to serve as the vertex index map. However, what you didn't anticipate, is that it makes the resultant type for the `vertex_index` property map (`boost::property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::type`) different, and hence the forwarding wrapper in `filtered_graph` doesn't fit the bill any more:

```
  template <typename G, typename EP, typename VP, typename Property>
  typename property_map<G, Property>::type
  get(Property p, filtered_graph<G, EP, VP>& g)
  {
    return get(p, const_cast<G&>(g.m_g));
  }
```

If you can afford to just switch to `vecS`, I'd go for that. Otherwise, think carefully about your requirements and the implications. Notably, your `VertexContainerSelector` choice of `listS` results in `vertex_descriptor` with both reference and iterator stability. Any `vertex_descriptor` from the filtered_graph should be valid for the main graph and vice versa¹. Why not just keep the same map:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1017398cbc58d84)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/filtered_graph.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp> // print_graph

template <typename T> using AddIndex = boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, T>;

template <
    typename VertexProperty,
    typename EdgeProperty = boost::no_property, 
    typename Base = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, AddIndex<VertexProperty>, EdgeProperty> >
struct MutableGraph : Base {
    using BoostBase = Base;

    MutableGraph(std::size_t n = 0) : BoostBase(n) {}
    using BoostBase::operator=;
};

int main() {
    using Graph = MutableGraph<boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, int> >;
    using vertex_descriptor = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    Graph g;
    auto a = add_vertex({1, 0}, g);
    auto b = add_vertex({2, 0}, g);
    auto c = add_vertex({3, 0}, g);
    auto d = add_vertex({4, 0}, g);
    add_edge(a, b, g);
    add_edge(a, c, g);
    add_edge(b, d, g);

    std::set<int> C{1,2}, H{/*3,*/4}; // vertex_descriptors I collect
    auto id = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    std::function<bool(vertex_descriptor)> vertexes_filter = [id, &C, &H](vertex_descriptor v) {
        auto index = id[v];
        return C.count(index) || H.count(index);
    };

    boost::filtered_graph<Graph, boost::keep_all, decltype(vertexes_filter)> auxilary(g, boost::keep_all(), vertexes_filter);

    auto aux_id = id;
    print_graph(g,        id,     std::cout << "\n---- Original\n");
    print_graph(auxilary, aux_id, std::cout << "\n---- Filtered\n");
}
```

Prints:

```
---- Original
1 <--> 2 3 
2 <--> 1 4 
3 <--> 1 
4 <--> 2 

---- Filtered
1 <--> 2 
2 <--> 1 4 
4 <--> 2
```

Which is precisely what you'd want.

### Side Notes

Note the simplifications in the code. Your `MutableGraph` class can be written as:

```
template <
    typename VertexProperty,
    typename EdgeProperty = boost::no_property, 
    typename Base = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, AddIndex<VertexProperty>, EdgeProperty> >
struct MutableGraph : Base {
    using BoostBase = Base;

    MutableGraph(std::size_t n = 0) : BoostBase(n) {}
    using BoostBase::operator=;
};
```

Although even those two members can be simply omitted for the usage in this example (the `operator=` will still be generated correctly by the compiler).

¹ except perhaps for the filtered ones...

### BONUS

Update in response to the comments: you can "automate" the type forwarding by specializing the `boost::property_map<>` trait:

```
namespace boost {
    // overriding the typedef to take the types from the BoostBase instead:
    template <typename Tag, typename... Args>
        struct property_map<MyGraph<Args...>, Tag> : property_map<typename MyGraph<Args...>::BoostBase, Tag> {
        };
}
```

That's all. Now you can do the printing from within a function that doesn't know what type of graph it is dealing with:

```
template <typename WhateverGraph>
void some_naive_user_function(WhateverGraph const& g, std::ostream& os) {
    // we don't know whether WhateverGraph is filtered or not, but we don't care
    print_graph(g, get(boost::vertex_index, g), os);
}
```

The `get(boost::vertex_index, g)` just works due to the specialization:

```
boost::filtered_graph<Graph, boost::keep_all, decltype(vertexes_filter)> auxilary(g, boost::keep_all(), vertexes_filter);

some_naive_user_function(g,        std::cout << "\n---- Origina (via naive user function)\n");
some_naive_user_function(auxilary, std::cout << "\n---- Filtered (via naive user function)\n");
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b0b31f0e6936cc)</kbd>**

Comment: Actually listS selector was chosen because I don't need iterator/descriptor invalidation and later I'll have to delete vertexes be descriptors.

Comment: And I likely to forward this filtered_graph in other function as usual graph, and there I need to get its property map. Is this possible without choosing vecS as selector?

Comment: Doesn't my code show how to do it? I'm **not** using `vecS` as a selector.

Comment: I see. But according to your example I'll have to forward vertex_index_map of original graph to function together with the filtered_graph. Can I keep out of this?

Comment: No, but you can hint the library you want to do this. All it takes is to [override the type trait](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b0b31f0e6936cc), looks like. Note that we do the printing from inside `some_naive_user_function` now and we don't care whether it is `MyGraph` or the `filtered_graph<>` adaptation of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184340/discussion-between-sehe-and-zabaz).

Comment: Yeah, overidding property_map worked for me!! Thank a lot!